# Bash pipes not working with my scripts

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have written two scripts. One is `myscipt1.sh` which reads a sequence of integer numbers (provided as arguments) and reports a final number:

```
[user@pc user] ./myscript1.sh 34 45 67 234
[user@pc user] 1200
```

In the above example, the script returns `1200`.
Another script `myscript2.sh` takes a string as input and returns a sequence of integer numbers:

```
[user@pc user] ./myscript2.sh a string to provide
[user@pc user] 364 465 786 34 22 1
```

I want to call `myscript1.sh` by passing the result of `myscript2.sh`, so I tried:

```
[user@pc user] ./myscript2.sh my_string | ./myscript1.sh
```

But I have no luck as `myscript1.sh` (wich performs a check on the number of arguments passed, exiting of no arguments are passed) reports that no arguments were passed.

Looks like Bash have problems when I use pipes with scripts I write. How to do?

Comment: However some commands like `echo` and `ls` can be used in pipes... I do not understand why...

Comment: `echo` and `ls` can write to standard output, and therefore appear on the *left* side of a pipe. They can appear on the right side of a pipe, but since they do not read from standard input, they ignore whatever they receive from the pipe, much like `myscript1.sh` seems to be doing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can run it as:

```
./myscript1.sh $(./myscript2.sh my_string)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `xargs`

```
[user@pc user] ./myscript2.sh my_string | xargs ./myscript1.sh
```

Answer (score 3):

Pipes do not work that way.

A pipe gets the output from a program/script and sends it *as standard input* to another program/script, *not* as command-line arguments. For example, you can use `readline` to read the data piped from the first program.

You should use `xargs` (as Joucks said while I was writing :) ) to do that.

Comment: Thankyou for the explaination. Now I understand :)

Answer (score 2):

If you *want* to use pipes, then rewrite your script(s) so that they expect their input not as arguments but read it from stdin:

```
input=$1  # old version

read input  # new version
```

Then you can use pipes the way you did.